# Frobenius twist of a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, fields, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ (not necessarily perfect). Consider the Frobenius endomorphism $F : k \to k$, $x \mapsto x^p$. I am curious about what happens when we take $k$ as a $k$-vector space, and restrict scalars along $F$. We get a new $k$-vector space $F_*(k)$, and I wonder how does it look (possibly even when $k$ is perfect)? Can we give a basis for $F_*(k)$? Is it finite dimensional?

I will also be interested if we can say something more generally about $F_*(V)$ for $V$ a finite dimensional $k$ vector space.

I first asked the question on [MathStack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248670/frobenius-twist-of-a-field) 4 months ago. Someone pointed out the simple reformulation of the question,

> Find a basis for $k$ as a $k^p$-vector space.

Surely it should be classical/elementary but I could not find a reference. Thank you

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07P0